# cannot import name 'BisectingKMeans' from 'sklearn.cluster' (C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\__init__.py)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, cluster-computing

When I try to use `sklearn.cluster.BisectingKMeans` in my jupyter notebook, an ImportError occured. It is said in the [document](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.BisectingKMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.BisectingKMeans) that this method is new in version 1.1, and my `scikit-learn` version is `1.1.3`.
I was using the base environment so it's not an issue of lacking package in current environment.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx1Jj.png)

I've tried upgrade the scikit-learn package, but it doesn't help.
Can anyone give me a hint of what is going on here？ Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on my machine:

`from sklearn.cluster import BisectingKMeans`

Also:

```
import sklearn
sklearn.__version__
> 1.1.2
```

Maybe you have a typo?

Comment: When I use `sklearn.__version__` in jupyter notebook, it turns out the version is `1.0.2`, and I think that's the reason why it cannot import BisectingKMeans. It worked when I restart the jupyter notebook. Thanks!